# Tinypass Fetching access details

Tags: php, html, payment

I am trying to fetch user's access details of TinyPass resource.

I am just starting to try to integrate it and using example codes.

```
    $params = array();
    $params["rid"] =  $rid;
    $params["user_ref"] = $username;
    $result = TinyPass::fetchAccessDetails($params, 1, 200);
    echo $result->getTotal();
```

But I am getting an Uncaught Exception API error on above line ($result=...)

Is there anybody who can give me some helping hand please?

PS: I am trying to send my custom PHP site's username to tinypass and later, want to fetch that user's data.

Here is my code

```
$rid = "PW_74296909";
$store = new TPAccessTokenStore();
$store->loadTokensFromCookie($_COOKIE);
$token = $store->getAccessToken($rid);
if($token->isAccessGranted()) {
    //Access granted! Display requested resource to the user
    echo 'WEELCOOOE';
} else {
    //Access denied! Proceed with the next steps and display a Tinypass button...

    $resource = new TPResource($rid, "Site wide premium content access");

    $po1 = new TPPriceOption(".50", "24 hours");
    $po2 = new TPPriceOption(".99", "1 week");
    $offer = new TPOffer($resource, array($po1, $po2));

    /*$request = new TPPurchaseRequest($offer);
    $buttonHTML = $request->setCallback("myFunction")->generateTag();

    //output button HTML in the place where Tinypass button is supposed to be rendered
    echo $buttonHTML;
    */

    //set user reference (username in this case)
    $username='member';


    $purchaseRequest = new TPPurchaseRequest($offer);
    $purchaseRequest->setUserRef($username);
    $link = $purchaseRequest->generateLink("http://localhost/Tinypass/index.php?action=success", "http://localhost/Tinypass/index.php?action=success");
    $buttonHTML= '<a href="'.$link.'" style="color:white; font-size:20px;">BUY IT</a>';

    //$buttonHTML = $purchaseRequest->setCallback("myFunction")->generateTag();
    echo $buttonHTML;

    $params = array();
    $params["rid"] =  $rid;
    $params["user_ref"] = $username;
    $result = TinyPass::fetchAccessDetails($params, 1, 200);
    echo $result->getTotal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should just be using the singular function for this:

```
$result = Tinypass:fetchaccessDetail(array('rid'=>$rid,'user_ref'=>$userref));
if ($result) {echo "<!-- "; print_r($result); echo " -->";}
```

If you do use the plural function, try something other than getTotal:

```
$results = TinyPass::fetchAccessDetails($params, 1, 200);
if (count($results['data') > 0) {
    foreach ($results['data'] as $record) {
        echo "<!-- "; print_r($record); echo " -->";
    }
}
```

It seems more like it is the singular function you will be needing though, which gives you slightly more information than the plural one. http://developer.tinypass.com/main/restapi

If all is working you should get back an array with the values listed there as array keys.
Note: fetchAccessDetails still returns 'user_email' not 'email' as the API page suggests.

If you're still having troubles (as I was) another thing you can do is edit the file TinyPassGateway.php where those functions are and in each of those functions on the line before:

```
throw $e;
```

add:

```
return $e->getMessage;
```

as you can get more direct debugging info back that way...